# Select not in subquery select Cosmos DB, syntax error

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'll figure it out eventualy but I want to put it out there:
This query:

```sql
SELECT distinct value e.siteid
FROM e IN c.events
where e.sensor = 'Air Temperature'
```

produces this result:

```
[ "07000619231FBD", "07000619236CDB", "09000619236C01", "09000619236BE3", "0A000619236BD7"]
```

This query works, as expected:

```sql
select *
from c
where c.id not in ([ "07000619231FBD", "07000619236CDB", "09000619236C01", "09000619236BE3", "0A000619236BD7"])
```

But the combination, i.e. subquery, gives syntax error:

```sql
select *
from c
where c.id not in
 (SELECT distinct value e.siteid
  FROM e IN c.events
  where e.sensor = 'Air Temperature')
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

(Your first query is also giving 400 BadREquest. I assume you miscopied, and actually executed this without `IN c.events`, as `c` is not defined in that query.)

Most likely the problem is that you are trying to do a query with cross-document join?**CosmosDB does not support joining different documents**. Only self-joins are allowed. Separate queries would work because you then eliminate the cross-document joining part.

See [Subquery documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-subquery#types-of-subqueries) explicitly saying (emphasis mine):

> There are two main types of subqueries:
>
> - Correlated: A subquery that references values from the outer query. The subquery is evaluated once for each row that the outer query processes.
> - Non-correlated: A subquery that's independent of the outer query. It can be run on its own without relying on the outer query.
>
> Note: **Azure Cosmos DB supports only correlated subqueries**.

Your original intent (separate queries) seems to be non-correlated query (cross-document join), but you have actually written a correlated one (self-join). What you CAN do, is as you have already done, just make those original 2 queries in succession.

---

If you by any chance actually DID want your subquery to only check air temperatures from the same document (self-join), then most likely you were missing the `ARRAY()` function:

```
select *
from c
where c.id not in
 (ARRAY(SELECT distinct value e.siteid
  FROM e IN c.events
  where e.sensor = 'Air Temperature'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! None of my posted queries gets a badrequest for me, copy/pasted in emulator and azure but that's beside the point. I was missing the ARRAY() function though so thank you